# How to prevent restrict PARTS of a web site to just INTRANET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, security

I am working on an asp.net mvc 5 project.  My clients want a program that will over their company INTRANET.... but certain parts of the project need to have INTERNET access to deal with external business partners...

Is it possible to make a single project / website where only parts are available over the INTERNET...

Of course the project has role based security trimming so you can only see the program features that you have access to .... but I suspect this will not be secure enough for this client... I suspect what they want is a way to totally restrict certain parts of the project from being accessed over the INTERNET even if the program user has the role that would allow them normally let them access these features...

The only thing that comes to mind is to extend the mvc framework with a custom security filter that checks the IP address to enforce what is available over the INTERNET .... Is this the best way to go?  Are there other options?

Does anyone know of any websites that would help with designing this solution (tutorial, examples, papers, etc..).

Comment: You can: 1. Create permissions to avoid access to specific areas 2. Make interactions using web-services

Comment: I am still trying to evaluate all of the solutions in my mind .... the two I am thinking about are building IP Blocking into the project and using the firewall to block the IP Addresses.... doing the IP blocking from within the application allows content sensitive blocking ... I am using Microsoft Identity 2.0 for security ... the question is how secure is this ... If I use the firewall to block to trusted companies is Identity secure enough to prevent most (all?) hacking?